# Thread safe collection for indexed access

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Do we have a thread-safe version of ArrayList that supports index-based access.

I could not find a counterpart for ArrayList in the concurrent package, as we have for LinkedList(ConcurrentLinkedQueue).
The blocking versions dont suit for my purpose.

I need to create a thread safe 'sorted' arraylist - hopefully by inheriting an available vanilla thread-safe version.

Answer (score 0):

Though deprecated, you can save yourself of all the headaches by using a  [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to achieve every bit of performance gain, below should work at most cases:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<SomeType>())
```

Comment: Was looking for a CAS based option ,if there.On another note - what does Collections.synchronizedList on an arraylist give us - that is not available in a vector?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  But there's almost certainly not going to be a better solution, algorithmically speaking.

Comment: @IUnknown I do not know much about Vector. But it is always a good Idea to avoid using deprecated libraries. They are deprecated for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) if iteration is a lot more frequent than modification.

Comment: Sorting on a CopyonWrite or a inherited class wont work - it will result in O(N) swaps/sets - which would be very taxing on performance

Comment: You would need to initialize the CopyOnWriteArrayList to a sorted state.  At that point if list insertions/deletions are infrequent then you may get better performance than with a synchronized ArrayList; if insertions/deletions are frequent then performance is going to be crap.